# Trigger S3 upload event periodically after 1st manual upload

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I have designed a solution which triggers a lambda function on a manual S3 file upload through an Event notification. My Lambda processes some data depending on the uploaded file.

I now want to trigger that S3 Event for the same file once every 24 hours after the 1st manual upload is done.

So the initial flow is -
Manual upload to s3 -> S3 Event Notification -> Trigger Lambda

New flow that I want -
Manual upload to s3 -> S3 Event Notification -> Trigger Lambda ->(Every 24 hours)-> Regenerate S3 Event Notification and Trigger Lambda

Is there a way I can achieve this? Maybe AWS GLUE (but not sure how to).

For the new flow, it is mandatory to have a manual upload since Lambda will process the file uploaded in the initial upload upon every run.

Comment: You could use the event bridge scheduler to create a schedule that triggers the lambda function periodically - see: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-eventbridge-scheduler/

Answer (score 0):

There is no ready-to-use service to replay messages on that large a schedule on AWS. SQS has [message timers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-timers.html) which could come useful for your task, but they are capped at 15 minutes.

You will have to build such a service yourself:

1. Create a DynamoDB table to store the processing state of each S3 object. Hash the object URL (`s3://bucket/key`) and use the first several bits of the hash for the partition key; use the timestamp of the next update for the sort key. Add the full object URL as an attribute.
2. Create a Lambda function which would put an entry to this table when the initial upload happens.
3. Create a Lambda function to process this table. We will call it the "replay Lambda"

   1. Read all entries from the table which have the update time larger than 24 hours ago (across all possible partition key values)
   2. Filter out the S3 objects which have since been deleted
   3. For existing objects:

      1. Generate the S3 events for each object and call the processing Lambda (asynchronously)
      2. Update the table entries, adding 24 hours to the processing time for every one of them
   4. For non-existing objects, delete the table entries
4. Create an EventBridge schedule to call the "replay Lambda" every minute or however frequently you want to so that.

That's the general idea. You might want to tweak it a little bit, depending on the answers to these questions:

1. What if the the replay Lambda falls behind? Do you want to postpone re-processing of your records for 24 hours since the original time or since the time the Lambda was called?
2. What if the replay does not complete by the time the next one is scheduled?

   You might want to put a timeout on the "replay Lambda" so that no concurrent executions ever happen.
3. What if you processing Lambda fails or hits the concurrency limit? How many times do you want to retry? Do you still want to replay in 24 hours if it's failing all the time?

   Instead of calling the processor asynchronously, you might want to put the messages on SQS queue to throttle them, or call it synchronously and wait for its results.